# Kendo MVC with Inline Editing Default Datetime of DateTime.Now showing page refresh time

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo MVC Grid that uses Inline editing. When I click "Add New Record" it is supposed to default the entry to DateTime.Now. The issue is that this value doesn't update, it continues to show the time the page was loaded instead of the time when the row is added.

I have tried to set it in the editor template and the model and I am getting the same result. My guess is I would have to set the javascript but cant find how to do this with inline fields and select the right DateTimePicker to update the value on. How can I have this default value be set when the add new record button is clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the DefaultValue in the DataSource Model definition the DateTime.Now value will get serialized as part of the initialization script.

If you need this to by dynamic you can add an Edit event handler and check if the model instance edited is a newly created one. If so set the date field to the current date and time:

```
      function onEdit(e){
        if(e.model.isNew()){
            e.model.set("MyDateField",new Date());
        }
      }
```

Here is an [example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mmFvOdEC09pGHx8w32).